# How can i retrieve a user information from users table and handle error if user does not exist?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on an MLM website trying to pull the users in a binary TREE in the blade view, it works for the first Three users because the user where such ID in query exists. but for users who don't have descendants it throws back error.
Please how can i retrieve a user information from users table and handle error if user does not exist?

my route:

```
Route::get('{id}/genealogy-tree', 'UsersController@show_genealogy')->name('genealogy-tree');
```

my controller:

```
public function show_genealogy($id)
{
    // $headuser = User::findOrFail($id);
    // $headuser_id = $headuser->id;
    if (User::findOrFail($id)->exists()) {
        $headuser = User::findOrFail($id);
        $headuser_id = $headuser->id;
    } else {
        $headuser = null;
        $headuser_id = null;

    }
    #-------------------------------------------------------
    if (User::where('l_id',  $headuser_id)->exists()) {
        $lfu = User::where('l_id',  $headuser_id)->first();
    } else {
        $lfu = null;
    }
    if (User::where('r_id',  $headuser_id)->exists()) {
        $rfu = User::where('r_id',  $headuser_id)->first();
    } else {
        $rfu = null;
    }

    // return view('users.genealogy-tree', compact('headuser','lfu','rfu'));
    #--------------------------------------------------------
    if (User::where('l_id',  $lfu->id)) {
        $lsu = User::where('l_id',  $lfu->id)->first();
    } else {
        $lsu = null;
    }       
    
    if (User::where('r_id',  $lfu->id)->exists()) {
        $rsu = User::where('r_id', $lfu->id)->first();
    }  else {
        $rsu = null;
    } 

    if (User::where('l_id',  $rfu->id)->exists()) {
        $ltu = User::where('l_id',  $rfu->id)->first();
    } else {
        $ltu = null;
    } 
    if (User::where('r_id',  $rfu->id)->exists()) {
        $rtu = User::where('r_id',  $rfu->id)->first();
    } else {
        $rtu = null;
    } 
    #--------------------------------------------------------

    return view('users.genealogy-tree', compact('headuser','lfu','rfu','lsu','rsu','ltu','rtu'));
    // return $lfu;
}
```

my view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table" style="align:center; border:o; text-align:center">
    <tr height="150" >
        <td></td>
        @isset($headuser)
        <td colspan="6"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $headuser->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #45fc03 !important; font-size: 1000%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$headuser->name ? $headuser->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$headuser->network_bonus ? $headuser->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$headuser->donation_sum ? $headuser->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$headuser->level ? $headuser->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="6"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 1000%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="150">
        @isset($lfu)
        <td colspan="4"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $lfu->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #b6fc03 !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$lfu->name ? $lfu->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$lfu->network_bonus ? $lfu->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$lfu->donation_sum ? $lfu->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$lfu->level ? $lfu->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="4"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset
        @isset($rfu)
        <td colspan="4"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $rfu->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #b6fc03 !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$rfu->name ? $rfu->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$rfu->network_bonus ? $rfu->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$rfu->donation_sum ? $rfu->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$rfu->level ? $rfu->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="4"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset
    </tr>

     <tr height="150" style="color: #f4fc03; font-size: 130%;">
       
        @isset($lsu)
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $lsu->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #f4fc03 !important;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$lsu->name ? $lsu->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$lfu->network_bonus ? $lfu->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$lsu->donation_sum ? $lsu->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$lsu->level ? $lsu->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset
        @isset($rsu)
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $rsu->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #b6fc03 !important;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$rsu->name ? $rsu->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$rsu->network_bonus ? $rsu->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$rsu->donation_sum ? $rsu->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$rsu->level ? $rsu->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset

        @isset($ltu)
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $ltu->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #f4fc03 !important;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$ltu->name ? $ltu->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$ltu->network_bonus ? $ltu->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$ltu->donation_sum ? $ltu->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$ltu->level ? $ltu->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset
        @isset($rtu)
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="{{route('genealogy-tree', $rtu->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: #b6fc03 !important;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div"> 
        <p>User Name: {{$rtu->name ? $rtu->name : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Network Worth: {{$rtu->network_bonus ? $rtu->network_bonus : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Donations: {{$rtu->donation_sum ? $rtu->donation_sum : 'No Record'}}</p>
        <p>Current Level: {{$rtu->level ? $rtu->level : 'No Record'}}</p>     
        </div></a>
        </td>
        @else
        <td colspan="2"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x" style="color: gray !important; font-size: 700%;"></i>
        <div class="tree_div">
            <br> 
        <p>{{'No User'}}</p>   
        </div></a>
        @endisset

    </tr>
   


    <!-- <tr height="150" style="color: #fcb603; font-size: 100%;">
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
        <td> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></td>
    </tr> -->
    

</table>
```

enter code here

Comment: Please add the error message to you your question.

Comment: And reduce the amount of code to just that which is useful to reproduce the error. We don’t need to see the entire view code.

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
http://project.test/4/genealogy-tree

Comment: and error message begins when there is no user having descendants get involved, i have conditioned the code in controller and view carefully yet i am still having errors

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information

Comment: Thanks, it worked checking if empty first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first()` returns null when a record is not found, you just need to check for null before using the variable.

You can use `optional(..)` to avoid null issues or the null function accessor `$var?->function(…)`

The problem in your controller is because you first try to find the user matching `$headuser_id` with the code:

```
if (User::where('l_id',  $headuser_id)->exists()) {
    $lfu = User::where('l_id',  $headuser_id)->first();
} else {
    $lfu = null;
```

You can simplify this to:

```
$lfu = User::where('l_id',  $headuser_id)->first();
```

As `first` will return the User or `null` if they don't exist.

But your error is caused by the code trying to use `$lfu->id` when `$lfu` it might be `null`:

```
if (User::where('l_id',  $lfu->id)) { ...
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

You either need to check for `empty($lfu)` or assign the variable in an `if`, when you find the user you can the use their `id` to search for the others:

```
$lsu = null;
$ltu = null;

if ($lfu = User::where('l_id',  $headuser_id)->first()) {
    $lsu = User::where('l_id',  $lfu->id)->first();
    $ltu = User::where('l_id',  $rfu->id)->first();
}
```